# Open new tab shorcut key in Opera

Tags: opera

In Chrome and Firefox I can open a link in a new tab by right click on the link and press T, but if I do this in Opera it opens the Inspect Element window instead.

How can I change this behavior to be the same as in Firefox and Chrome?

Comment: I don't even bother with that two-step process. Why not simply middle-click? I'm sure that would work in Opera same as it has for years in all other browsers.

Comment: I'm using a laptop, so no middle click

Comment: Have you tried mouse gestures? The learning curve is perhaps slightly steeper with a trackpad instead of a mouse, but it's intuitive enough. Try right-clicking on the link, keep holding the right mouse button down while you move down then up, then let go of the right mouse button.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you click a link in Opera...

- `Click` opens the link in the current tab
- `Shift+Click` opens in a new tab
- `Ctrl+Shift+Click` opens in a new background tab
- Pressing `E` in the right-click context menu also opens a new background tab

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to achieve this.

One of them is to use <kbd>keyboard</kbd> modifiers as **mtone** suggested but if you'd like Opera to handle background tabs the same way Google Chrome does, then you're better off doing this:

Install [AutoStack](https://addons.opera.com/extensions/details/autostack/) and backup Opera's menu config file as explained [here](http://my.opera.com/Tamil/blog/edit-menu-setup) then proceed.

Open the config file `standard_menu.ini` in a text editor ([Notepad++](http://notepad-plus-plus.org) works well).

The file is usually located at:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Opera\ui\
```

Search for `[Link Popup Menu]` and add one of these entries:

```
Item, "Open link in New Background Tab"= Open link in background page, "urlinfo",,, "Mail Compose Bold"
OR
Item, "Open link in New Background Tab"= Open link in background page, "urlinfo",,, "Thread Button"
```

Now search for `[Hotclick Popup Menu]`. When you've found it, add this line among the other entries:

```
Item, "Search in background tab"= Copy,,,,"Search Web" & Paste and go background
```

Where you place these lines will decide where it will turn up in the context menu so if you want them to show up as the first choice in their respective menus, make sure you place them at the top.

Restart Opera. Now when you select some text and right-click it, you should see **Search in background tab** among the items in the context menu. Clicking on it will either send the selected text to your default search engine or if it's a URL, Opera will load it in the background page like Google Chrome does.

Also **Open link in New Background Tab** shows up when you right click a link. What it does is self-explanatory. Based on your choice, you should see one of these in the context menu:

> [image: Sample menus]

Comment: You do _not_ need to install AutoStack to achieve what you want, nor do I understand why you're going on about the "Search in background tab" option - that's not even remotely related to what the OP asked for and I would recommend you edit your post. Instructions for editing the `standard_menu.ini` file are correct (hence no downvote), and it's the right way to go to edit the context menu entries, but again, it doesn't explain how to do what the OP wants to do.